# How I can send same input value by triggering click to two functions?

Tags: javascript, function, dom-events

I'm tying to send same input value to two functions but it's not working. Let me show the summary of my codes.

```
const btn = document.querySelector('.btn')

btn.addEventListener('click',getTogether)


function getTogether(event){

    event.preventDefault();

const country = document.querySelector('.input-text').value ;

    getChart(country);
    getGlobal(country)
}

function getChart(country){
......
}

function getGlobal(country){
......
}
```

Is it possible to send same input value to two functions as arguments or is there any better way? Please let me know.

Comment: What is the issue exactly?

Comment: Thanks for your comment.i need to send same input value to two functions so i can work with that argument into those functions.is there any better way? ( i'm also using click event)

Comment: You state in the question that its not working, but it should work as is. As for better, well this one is alright

Comment: .i forgot to mention i'm actually using another function into second function.can i take same argument being a inner function?

Comment: Uncaught ReferenceError: country is not defined <-- into second function

Comment: So you're using code that isn't the code you've given?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure what your issue is, but does the below code help?

```js
const btn = document.querySelector('.btn')
const country = document.querySelector('.input-text')

btn.addEventListener('click', getTogether)

function getTogether(event) {
  event.preventDefault()
  getChart(country.value)
  getGlobal(country.value)
}

function getChart(country) {
  console.log("getChart called with:", country)
}

function getGlobal(country) {
  console.log("getGlobal called with:", country)
}
```

```html
<input type="text" class="input-text" />
<button class="btn">Click Me</button>
```

Comment: Thanks Sir.it's working...really appreciate your times.:3